# Como puedo invertir en ggplot2 la el sentido del eje ?, quedando el 0 en la parte superior

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image: ggplot2, invertir el eje y]

Cómo puedo cambiar el sentido del eje y?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: No se como escribir el código, para que el "0" en el eje y quede en la parte superior.

Comment: Muestranos el codigo con el que estas trabajando por favor

Comment: library(ggplot2)
# boxplot de dos factores con ggplot2
ggplot(df, aes(x=df[,2], y=df[,1], fill=df[,3])) +
  geom_boxplot() + 
  ggtitle("Profundidad del Nivel Freático (m)") +
  xlab("mes") + ylab("NF(m)")+ labs(fill = "pozo")

Comment: ¿Probaste agregando `coord_flip()`?

Comment: Gracias Patricio, coord_flip()= invierte la posición cartesiana de los ejes. Encontre en  ggplot2, se invierte con ylim(5,0).